# Splitting up EDM to reuse functionality across multiple projects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I currently have an ASP .NET MVC / EF4 project that contains many pieces of autonomous functionality such as a blogging, events, contests, wiki, etc.

The entities used by each system are all mapped to my database through one giant EDM file.

This works well for the main site, but I also have a few personal sites where I want to reuse just the blogging functionality from the mains ite.

My biggest problem is that due to the mac daddy EDM file, my blog sites have to constantly have their database schemas updated to reflect changes made to areas of functionality that they don't use (i.e. changes to the events system).

The only other gotcha is that there are some entities (Users and Tags) that have relationships with entities from each area of functionality, making it hard to simply split each area of functionality off into its own EDM.

With all of this said, I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to set this up.

Should I go down the road of splitting up the EDMs by each area (blogs, events, contests, wiki) and figuring out a way to maintain relationships for the User and Tag entities?

Or should I just perhaps be creating an EDM for each website that only maps the entities that it will actually need? The only problem with this is that my repository layer takes in a UnitOfWork/ObjectContext, and by creating new ObjectContexts for each site I'd have problems reusing my repository code.

Comment: Your site should work against viewmodels. Only in controllers you would use injection (DI, IoC) to push in your repositories and those will interact with EF context. If you started to think about the problem in this way - having the application work without any association to the datastore at all (that comes in later and it doesn't matter how you solve it, be it EF to SQL Server, XML storage, etc.). If you have problems splitting the EDM up, spend some time fixing up database schema, normalization, etc. Problems most likely stem from there.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a WCF service and then pass your data via a JSON contract. That way you'd have a central service that holds your EF data, and then just exposes functions based on what the your different applications need.

Its more short term work to setup (hopefully your service/repository layer was done with IoC in mind to allow it to be easily plugged in) but if your EF data changes a lot, it means you can update the one central service without having to update each of your clients apps.

There's a good reference thread here on S.O: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973017/where-to-find-good-wcf-video-tutorials